# how to set 2 cm margin in each side of my document

Tags: margins

Please I want to set 2 cm margin in each side of my pages(top,down,left,right) I have seen many many margin but I don't know how can I set the exact magins to have at the end 2 cm
I did

```
\setlength{\hoffset}{-0.57cm}
\setlength{\voffset}{-1.25cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0cm} 
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0mm} % 15 mm par def. 
\setlength{\topmargin}{1mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{0cm} % 1 cm par d�faut
\setlength{\headsep}{1.00cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{22cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{17cm} % 16 cm par d�f.
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0cm} % 1mm par def.
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{2\baselineskip} 
\setlength{\footskip}{2.5cm}
```

when I set `\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}`  I get the ooutput in this picture

[image: margin]

thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you know package `geometry`? If not please read the documentation (use `texdoc geometry` on your terminal/console.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use: `\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}` in your preamble. The geometry package will calculate all other parameters for you. You should never modify \hoffset and \voffset without serious reasons.

Comment: I still have the problem, here is the template I am using https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8-1FiuGK2JNZjRydmJKMkdwSWs/view

Comment: I still have this problem, this is urgent, I need this for tomorrow,

Comment: @djanahana: It's done. I had a few problems with the encoding of your sourcefile. Is there any place to post the (slightly) modified `aesm_edspia.cls` class file? I took the opportunity to correct some typos and comment the code (some packages loaded are obsolete).

Comment: thank you very much for your time and trying to help me, you couldn't post it in an answer? my email adress is noura.kali@yahoo.com

Comment: The problem is the code of the class is rather long, and I'm not sure it has a general interest. I'll post it in a moment.